# Call back function throwing error

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I'm trying to solve this async problem. I got the problem working.

However, after calling "done" callback it's throwing an error. I don't know why.

**Issue**:

> I want to print the task number once "Done" is invoked.
>   But it throws an
>   error saying TypeError: "callback" argument must be a function

**Problem:**

> A "TaskRunner" Constructor takes one argument, "concurrency", and
>   exposes one method "push" on its prototype. The "push" method takes
>   one argument "task" which is a  "function"
>
> Passing a task to a push method of a TaskRunner instance should
>   immediately execute (call/run/invoke) the task, unless the number
>   of currently running tasks exceeds the concurrency limit.

```js
function TaskRunner(concurrency) {
    this.count = concurrency;
    this.queue = [];
  }
  
  TaskRunner.prototype.push = function(task) {
    if (this.count === 0) {
      this.queue.push(task);
    } else {
      this.invoke(task);
    }
  }
  
  TaskRunner.prototype.invoke = function(task) {
    task.call(null, this.done.bind(this));
    this.count--;
  }
  
  TaskRunner.prototype.done = function(num) {
    console.log(`After Executing done: ${num}`)
    this.count++;
    this.execute();
  }
  
  TaskRunner.prototype.execute = function() {
    if (this.queue.length > 0) {
      var task = this.queue.shift();
      this.invoke(task);
    }
  }

  function factory(num) {
    return function exampleSimpleTask(done) {
      this.num = num;
      console.log("task", "Before " + new Date().getTime());
      setTimeout(done(num), 2000);
    }
  }


  var r = new TaskRunner(2);

r.push(factory(1));
r.push(factory(2));
r.push(factory(3));
```

EDIT: For some reason, on jsfiddle it runs fine but when I run the same code on my local it fails.

Please help.

Comment: `setTimeout(done(num), 2000);` that's not how you use setTimeout - setTimeout expects a function as the first argument, you are passing the result of calling a function'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing the `setTimeout` the *result*  of you function:

```
setTimeout(done(num), 2000);
```

This will call `done(num)` immediately and `setTimeout` will try to call whatever `done()` returned as through it were a function.

You should pass it a function that it can call instead:

```
setTimeout(() => done(num), 2000);
```

or [as @JaromandaX points out in the comment] you can take advantage of the options third argument of `setTimeOut` which will be passed into the callback function:

```
setTimeout(done, 2000, num);
```

this will call the function `done` and pass in `num`